# Is Google Spreadsheet script method clear({commentsOnly}) to delete comments on a range not working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a basic Google script function that deletes the comments on the first cell.
This doesn't work:

```
function deleteCommentinCellA1() {
  // Get cell A1 on the first sheet
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
 var cell = sheet.getRange("A1");

  cell.clear({commentsOnly : true});
}
```

even though the other [clear(options) provided by Google script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clear(Object)) work fine. I tried the same function with deleting format, content and even checked the other method `clearNotes()`, everything works fine.

My hunch is that I'm missing something specific about comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, it seems to be a reported issue:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1818

Comment: Thx.
Everyone who lands on this issue should follow your link and vote.

I get a known error on my very first Google Apps script...bad omen? :)